# Trouble using Notification API js

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, notifications

I'm facing an issue trying to implement notifications in my website.
In fact, I'm trying to make a function that calls `PHP` with an `ajax` request, in order to check with `mysql` if there are any notification. Then, if there is one/few notification(s), I get back from `PHP` the information I need, and display them using notification API. I do this every 5 seconds.

In fact, notifications are displayed in the top right corner, and I can only see the bottom of it.
Other weird fact, when I use function `alert();`, notifications are properly displayed.. This issue is happening with Firefox, but not on chromium.

So my question is, do you have any idea why notifications are not placed properly on firefox but not on Chromium? If you need any more information do not hesitate. Thanks in advance, and if you need it, here is some code :

With this two functions, I get what I need thanks to a php script.

```
function notifications() {
    $.ajax({ url: './get_notifications.php/',
        type: 'post',
        data: {"name": window.user},
        success: function(output) {
            if (output != "")
            {
                split_notifications(output);
            }
            else
                return;
        },
        failure: function() {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    }); 
}

function check_notifications() {
    setInterval(function() {
        notifications();
    }, 10000);
}
```

In this function, I just split information and then call another function, in charge of creating my notification.

```
function split_notifications(notif) {
    var tmp_notif = notif.split(";");
    var index = 0;
    while (tmp_notif[0].split(",,,")[index])
    {
        //!\\ When I put alert() HERE it's working
        display_notification(tmp_notif[1].split(",,,")[index], tmp_notif[2].split(",,,")[index], tmp_notif[0].split(",,,")[index]);
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

Here is the function that creates my notification :

```
function display_notification(title, message, someone) {
    {
        if(window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "denied") {
            Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {  // status is "granted", if accepted by user
               var project_notification = new Notification(title, { 
                   body: someone + " " + message + '\nSee more...',
                   icon: "../img/" + someone.split(" ")[1] + ".png"
               }); 
               project_notification.onclick = function() {
                   alert("");
               }
           });
       }
}
```